# How and when to use -mbig-endian gcc option on AArch64?

Tags: gcc, arm64

I tried to use `-mbig-endian` gcc option on AArch64 (Raspberry Pi 3 Model B with little-endian byte order configuration) with the intention of reading from and writing to the memory in big-endian byte order. I got the following error and the compilation terminated.

```
/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:11:11: fatal error: gnu/stubs-lp64_be.h: No such file or directory `#include <gnu/stubs-lp64_be.h>`
```

I actually went to that folder and couldn't find that file. Am I missing something?

The gcc online documentation says `-mbig-endian` option generates big-endian code. What exactly does that mean?

Answer (score 3):

You are not missing anything, but it seems than even gcc toolchains provided by ARM don't allow using `-mbig-endian` with [aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc](https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-a/8.3-2019.03/binrel/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-aarch64-linux-gnu.tar.xz?revision=2e88a73f-d233-4f96-b1f4-d8b36e9bb0b9&la=en), nor `-mlittle-endian` with  [aarch64_be-linux-gnu-gcc](https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-a/8.3-2019.03/binrel/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-aarch64_be-linux-gnu.tar.xz?revision=2f2b1067-b22e-4eaf-b4ff-e1bd205131e6&la=en): In both cases, a .h file related to the 'alien' endianess will be missing.

That probably means that you should just use aarch64_be-linux-gnu-gcc for cross-compiling big-endian aarch64 Linux executables. But you will still not be able to run those executables on a little-endian aarch64 Linux system.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yeah, your answer makes sense. I would like to know what `-mbig-endian` option does precisely.

Comment: According to the documentation, and as you were suspecting, it does [generate big endian code](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AArch64-Options.html). It is the default for aarch64_be-linux-gcc, but is not honored by the aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc 8.3 available from ARM.

Comment: I am not sure what a big-endian code is. My guess is the big-endian code is stored in the memory in big-endian byte order. Would the data access also be big-endian in this case?

Comment: Yes, the the data access also be big-endian in this case, the way it is with a ppc64 platform.